# .load() method to load .html file from parent directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following structure:

- folder1

  - index
- folder2

  - page to load

is it possible to load the page to load in a div in the index page, using `DIV.load()`? i've tried all possible path and it doesn't work. (`../folder2/page`, `./`, `/`, `..`)

it's a completely different question: [Dynamically load Web Components / HTML Imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607663/dynamically-load-web-components-html-imports)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load Web Components / HTML Imports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607663/dynamically-load-web-components-html-imports)

Comment: it's a completely different question

Answer (score 1):

try like :

```
$('#id_of_your div').load( "../folder2/test.html");
```

you can also load only a part from page to load like :

```
$('#id_of_your div').load( "../folder2/test.html #container");
```

link of documentation : http://api.jquery.com/load/

verify also if jquery is correctly loaded, and if any bug is logged in the console.

---

Try also another thing just to be sure that server doesn't block links with "../" :

change the structure of your code like :

```
* forder project
     - index
     - sub folder
          -page to load 1
          -page to load 2
```

Comment: I've loaded jquery:  <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> , and I'm sure it's loaded correctly becouse I'm using it to do other things that works.
There are no bugs

Comment: try in firefox to run page, and open console "F12", write : $('#id_of_your div').load( "../folder2/test.html"); with an existing id and page. and tell us the error that you get

Comment: i got that i can't access file in parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your directory index from folder1 then, it is not accessible, if you are using virtualhost or something like that, may be you can move your directory 'folder2' in 'folder1', i am not expert but it seems like that.

Hope this help!!

Comment: i can't move it in folder1, becouse other pages in other folders must access it

Comment: For example: localhost/index.html
This path is point to your folder 1, so server will be not allow back am i right ?

Comment: @Mehendra Kavathiya: server can allow if the page that lunch request is in the same server.

Comment: @llyas may be some miss understanding, but my point direct to <Directory "/home/mahendra/folder1"> if this is access point of domain/host then is it really possible to back ?