# How to load javascript es6 module determined at runtime?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, web-component, es6-modules, lit-element

I am developing a SPA which contains multiple dashboards. Each dashboard is a set of Web Components respecting a layout. These components are not known statically. They are determined at run-time.

What I want to achieve is the following scenario:

1. Application starts.
2. The application performs XHR to fetch dashboards representations from a REST service.
3. User sees dashboards listed by name.
4. User clicks on a dashboard item. (say dashboard 1)
5. The application determines the necessary components needed to load dashboard 1 (web components)
6. Load **web components** and their **dependencies**.

I am pretty aware of loading web components dynamically which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649225/6174341)

My actual problem is

> how to load a web component with their dependencies at run-time
>   without having to load duplicate dependencies?
>
> Are there any module formats or practices to follow when packaging the
>   web components?

Comment: There's [dynamic import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914712/es6-conditional-dynamic-import-statements) proposal, [already implemented in some browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import), which seems to fit your use case

Comment: IIRC webpack supports multiple entry points, and multiple component bundles, and figures out duplicate-free dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mapping from dashboard to the module that implements it, then you can just dynamic `import()` the necessary module. The JS module system will take care of not loading modules that have already been loaded, so common dependencies like `lit-element` will only be loaded once.

This deduplication works based on URL, so you have to make sure that you have one copy of a dependency installed via npm. `npm dedupe` will attempt to deduplicate your `node_modules/` folder, and `npm ls` will let you see the dependency tree.

All current browsers support dynamic `import()`, and most bundlers do too - as long as the argument is a string constant. This means that you can't compute the module URL based on the dashboard if you want to use a bundler. You need something like:

```js
const dashboardLoaders = {
  'dash-1': () => import('./dashboards/dash-1.js'),
  'dash-2': () => import('./dashboards/dash-2.js'),
  // etc...
};
```